# Angular JS update html with nested dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dictionary

I'm fairly new to AngularJS... and there is something that doesn't work at the moment.

I created a dictionary in the controller scope, and filled it up after http request. (key,value pair)

The dictionary gets created fine, and it doesn't show any error, but the HTML is not updating according to the ng-bind-html.

Is there a way to create the key-value pair dynamically and bind it to the HTML?

**Controller**

```
$scope.htmlData = {
            };
$http.get('SOME URL TO JSON').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.section_content.length; i++)
            {
                $scope.htmlData[data.section_content[i].name] = data.section_content[i];

            }
            console.log($scope.htmlData);


        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
```

**HTML**

```html
<!-- HOME PART 1: Welcome -->
<div class="row margin-bottom-50"  ng-bind-html="$scope.htmlData.title_text.content">

</div>

<!-- HOME PART 2: EQ COLUMN -->
<div class="row" style='background: #E6E7E8;'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
            <div class='col-md-4 home-info-panels' style="border-right: 1px solid black;" ng-bind-html="$scope.htmlData.info_column_1.content">
                
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-4 home-info-panels' style="border-right: 1px solid black;" ng-bind-html="$scope.htmlData.info_column_2.content">
                
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-4 home-info-panels' ng-bind-html="$scope.htmlData.info_column_3.content">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify `$scope`, just the property name.

So instead of

```
ng-bind-html="$scope.htmlData.info_column_3.content"
```

do

```
ng-bind-html="htmlData.info_column_3.content"
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't mark it right away. I had to wait before marking the answer